# searching for a particular object in array list and printing all the objects in array list

Tags: java, search, printing, arraylist

I have to implement a java application that demonstrates the use of array list of objects. I am using Students and I have a StudentTest class. I should be able to enter in details(which I have done). I'm just unsure how to search for a particular object in the array list by Student Number and also to print the array list. Any hints would be great thanks.

code so far:

```
package student;

public class Student {

    private String studentName;
    private String studentNo;
    private String email;
    private int year;

    public Student() {
        this.studentName = null;
        this.studentNo = null;
        this.email = null;
        this.year = -1;
    }

    public Student(String nName, String nNum, String nEmail, int nYr) {
        this.studentName = nName;
        this.studentNo = nNum;
        this.email = nEmail;
        this.year = nYr;
    }

    public void setStudentName(String newStudentName) {
        this.studentName = newStudentName;
    }

    public void setStudentNo(String newStudentNo) {
        this.studentNo = newStudentNo;
    }

    public void setEmail(String newEmail) {
        this.email = newEmail;
    }

    public void setYear(int newYear) {
        this.year = newYear;
    }

    public String getStudentName() {
        return studentName;
    }

    public String getStudentNo() {
        return studentNo;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

}
package student;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class studentTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


        List<Student> Students = new ArrayList();


        System.out.println("Enter number of students");
        int countStudents = input.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < countStudents; i++) {
            Student student1 = new Student();
            System.out.println("Enter details for student: " + (i + 1));

            System.out.println("Enter name: ");
            student1.setStudentName(input.next());

            System.out.println("Enter Number: ");
            student1.setStudentNo(input.next());

            System.out.println("Enter email: ");
            student1.setEmail(input.next());

            System.out.println("Enter year: ");
            student1.setYear(input.nextInt());
            Students.add(student1);



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Override `equals` method for class `Student`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a `equals()` method in your `Student` class, that will return true if 2 students have same `studentNo`, else `false`.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object ob) {

    if (!(ob instanceof Student)) { 
        return false;
    }

    return ob.getStudentNo().equals(this.getStudentNo());
}
```

Now, you can just use `contains` method to check whether a `student` is in the `List` or not.

**UPDATE**: -

Also, you need to override `hashcode` method, whenever you are `overriding` `equals` method, to maintain the general contract between them. So override `hashcode` that would calculate the `hashcode` of your `instances` based only on the fields on which you are comparing your `objects`

So, you need to calculate `hashcode` using `studentNo`.

```
@Override
public int hashcode() {
    return this.getStudentNo().hashCode(); 
}
```

- HashCode calculating `algorithm` should be such that, if two instances are equal, their hashcode should also be equals
- It should return same value for same instance everytime, of course when the instance has not been modified.
- Two different instances can have the same hashcode

**As suggested by @hyde in the comment**: -

If this is just too much work for you, then you can just have a different method, that does the same task as `equals` method, say, `checkEquals()`, and `ignore` overriding `equals()` method. But in that case, you would have to do `iteration` on your `List` and for each list element, invoke this `method` with the `student` to compare.

```
for(Student student: studentList) {
    if (student.checkEquals(myStudent)) {
        System.out.println("True");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is more of a nitpick, but in this case it would be better to name the method differently, like isSame(), and using loop to search. Even (or maybe especially) in school work, overriding equals should mean also overriding hashCode.

Comment: @hyde. Oh yeah. I completely forgot to quote that. Goind to edit.

Comment: @hyde. Yeah I think I have improved my post, to consider both the aspects. thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm actually looking to search for a string(student number) in the Student object in the array list.

Comment: @Rob. Then you can override a `toString` method, that returns the `studentNo` for that student.. And each time you print your `student`, the studentNo will get printed.

Comment: public int hashCode() { return this.getStudentNo().hashCode(); } should do it for the code of this answer, where equals uses just that one field.